# breaking up double precision numbers in UDP transfer in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, double

My program currently sends and receives UDP packets, and breaks them up in 16 bit chunks when it receives them in order to process the incoming data. Part of that incoming data is two double precision numbers (64 bits on my machine). How can I recombine the 16 bit chunks into a double precision format? They're sent to me in that format but I've found that I cannot recombine by OR-ing together, shift bits, etc. but I can only receive them 16 bits at a time. Any idea?

so an incoming packet I receive will have a 64bit double precision number, but it gets read 16 bits at a time: 0x9080 0x1145 0x42AF 0x45F3 - I need to assemble those back to a double precision number.

This is what I've tried so far:
"in_data" is a 16 bit pointer to my incoming UDP packet...

```
        double cal1 = 0;
        double cal2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)     
        {
            in_data++;
            cal1 |= *in_data;
            if (i < 3) cal1 << 16;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {
            in_data++;  
            cal2 |= *in_data;
            if (i < 3) cal2 << 16;
        }
```

I realize this code is incorrect, but I had to try it before I learned it.

Comment: Could you please provide some code showing how you are encoding the data on the wire and what you have tried to reassemble the data into 64-bit space that you then cast to double?

Comment: Byte ordering is first thing which comes to mind. Other than that, the question is rather vague without specific examples.

Comment: Why only 16 bits at a time?

Comment: @SergeyA - most significant byte is sent first. 16 bit packets was specified to me. NEver had to work with float or double before, so this process is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just receiving raw bits, store them in an unsigned long long type.

```
unsigned long long bits;
bits |= packet1;
bits |= packet2 << 16;
bits |= packet3 << 32;
bits |= packet4 << 48;
```

Then when you need to parse it as a double, reinterpret the bits.

```
long double input = *((long double*)&bits);
```

Comment: So if packet1 is the MSB of the double precision format data being sent to me, the casting in your example will tell the system that the data stored in "bits" is actually already in double precision format?

Comment: Suggest `1ULL*packet4 << 48`

Comment: @JediEngineer you need to know the endianness on the system you're working with. In addition, the bits won't tell you what format the number is in, it's just data. What I'm doing is grabbing the address of the bits, casting to a different kind of pointer, and then reading the bits as though they were a different data type.

Comment: @Xirema, thanks. I think I follow you. My compiler complained about the casting though: "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules"

Comment: @Xirema, shouldn't the casting be `long double input = *((long double*)bits);` ? I think you were dereferencing the address to the pointer versus the data in memory.

Comment: bits isn't a pointer on its own. If you do it the way you're suggesting, it'll try to read the memory located at the address defined by bits and interpret it as a long double. Which would throw a seg fault, or at least result in bizarre behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use union or reinterpret_cast, populate 16bit array and use as double:

```
union U
{
  double d;
  short i[4];
};
```

Comment: Good way to promote implementation-defined behaviour :)